# Any way to skip time changing by android monkey tool

Tags: android, android-monkey

I am performing UI stress testing for app and as well as some other apps by using monkey tool.. But monkey is changing the time and which effects the logs timestamp.. This is causing annoying while debugging the issues(system/events logs)..

Is there a way to hardcode the time or not to touch the time while monkey exercising the apps..

-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the monkey in Android is a UI exerciser that is completely random by nature. I'm not sure with the monkey tool, but if you want to *harcode* UI Events and specifically make test scripts (a good idea, per what I've experienced), check out [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)

It basically lets you write scripts in Java to click on certain UI elements, open certain menus, etc, etc. It's very useful and that way you can avoid things you don't want happening.

It's also amazingly easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your input.. But i am thinking it is again an extra effort to implement those customized tests.. so thought of tweaking current process to solve my problem.